# how to select random values in query

Tags: postgresql

I need to list 30 products mixing some stores like this:

```
1 - product a - store 1
2 - product b - store 1
3 - product c - store 1
4 - product d - store 5
5 - product e - store 5
6 - product f - store 5
7 - product g - store 3
8 - product h - store 3
and so on
```

How to ensure query returns stores mixed in result?

```
table products
id
title
store_id
```

Comment: If you are sampling from part of your table, you can use `TABLESAMPLE` in the [FROM clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) of your SELECT statement to mix up the results. I have experimented with this and it does not work at all when you try to sample 100% of the table. I experimented on a 47 row table. At I didn't start getting any mixing until I dropped from 100% to 90%.

Comment: You can use this syntax: `select * from products order by random() limit 30`. If you needed randomize limit you can use random function after limit clause too.  `select * from products limit random()*100`